# How can the following problem solved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If Fatima sells 60 identical toys at a 40% discount on the printed price, then she makes 20% profit. Ten of these toys are destroyed in fire. While selling the rest, how much discount should be given on the printed price so that she can make the same amount of profit?

A) 30%
B) 25%
C) 24%
D) 28%

I have tried solving it logically by taking 100 as the printed price and applying 40% discount which makes the price 60 and then finding the profit of 20% which is 12

But I believe this is wrong approach to this question, Would really help if someone could help me with this

Comment: You posted in Lin Alg, why haven’t you tried Lin Alg?

Answer (score 1):

Let Cost Price(**CP**) of 1 item=**x**
total cost price(**TCP**)=**60x**
Let Marked Price(**MP**) of 1 item=**y**
**TMP=60y**

Selling Price(SP) = **0.6 times MP**  (40% discount)
$$TSP=60\cdot(0.6y)  
=36y  $$

Profit(P) = TSP-TCP
P= **36y-60x**
$$P_{percent}=\frac{P\cdot100}{CP}=20$$
$$P_{percent} =\frac{(36y-60x)\cdot 100}{60x} = 20$$
Solving, **y=2x**

Now,
**TCP=60x**  (CP remains same)
**TMP=50y**  (only 50 items)

Let discount % be **p**
$$TSP=50y(1-\frac{p}{100})$$

Profit(P) = TSP-TCP
$$P = 50y(1-\frac{p}{100})-60x  $$
$$P_{percent} =\frac{(50y(1-\frac{p}{100})-60x)\cdot 100}{60x}$$
which is again **20**.

Solve   $$\frac{(50y(1-\frac{p}{100})-60x)\cdot 100}{60x}=20$$

by substituting **y=2x**
**x** gets cancelled.

You get **p=28**

So, discount on Marked Price(MP) = ***28%***

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Indicate with $P$ the printed price and with $x$ new discount, then we have

- profit with $60$ items $60\cdot (1-0.40) \cdot P$
- profit with $50$ items $50\cdot (1-x) \cdot P$